# VSU 2012 - Relase Project error on other computer (SQLCE)

Tags: c++, database, local-database

Recently, i finished my large application project. I used database : SQL Compact, because i was reading and i read, that it's a local database, so i was very happy :). Troubles coming soon when I finally finished my application. The first thing, which i did, is try to open it on other computer, without difference software (visual studios etc.).

But it's error with SQL CE.

I searched solution for it for one week, but all, which i found it's for older versions of Visual Studio.

I'm have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Edition (i'm writting in C++) and i don't know what i can do now.

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): Unable to load
>   the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the
>   ADO.NET provider version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL
>   Server Compact. See article 974247 in the Knowledge Base for more
>   details.

Please help me ;X

Comment: What is the error? Hard to help if we don't know what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact is included on the Visual Studio 2012 DVD. You can start the installation using the following steps

- Insert your Visual Studio 2012 DVD
- Open the DVD in Windows Explorer
- Navigate to the *packages* folder
- Navigate to the *SSCE40* folder
- Run `SSCERuntime_x64-???.exe` for 64bit and `SSCERuntime_x86-???.exe` for 32bit where `???` indicates the language. For instance the 64 bit English language version is named `SSCERuntime_x64-enu.exe`

Choose the installation options that meet your requirements and start the installation.

If you do not have your Visual Studio 2012 DVD handy you can download SQL Server Compact from the [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) website.

Comment: Yes i know, but I want to giving my application to my friends without installing SQL Server Compact. :P

Comment: If your application _relies_ on SQL Server Compact then you _need_ to install SQL Server Compact on any computer you want to run it on.

Comment: I know that I can deploy it with application, but all tutorials on network is for vs 2008,2010 and my vs ultimate 2012 doesn't have this options. ;(